# Can't seem to extract text from element using BS4

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the name on this web page: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29

the element i am trying to grab it from is

```
<h1 class="hover_item_name" id="largeiteminfo_item_name" style="color: 
rgb(210, 210, 210);">AK-47 | Redline</h1>
```

I am able to search for the ID "largeiteminfo_item_name" using selenium and retrieve the text that way but when i duplicate this with bs4 I can't seem to find the text.

Ive tried searching class "item_desc_description" but no text could be found there either. What am I doing wrong?

```
a = soup.find("h1", {"id": "largeiteminfo_item_name"})
a.get_text()

a = soup.find('div', {'class': 'item_desc_description'})
a.get_text()
```

I expected "AK-47 | Redline" but received '' for the first try and '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' for the second try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are trying to extract is not present in the HTML page, I guess it might be generated aside with JavaScript (just guessing).

[image]

However I managed to find the info in the div "market_listing_nav".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests

lnk = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29"
res = requests.get(lnk)

soup = bs4(res.text, features="html.parser")
elem = soup.find("div", {"class" : "market_listing_nav"})

print(elem.get_text())
```

This will output the following

```
Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
                    >
                                        AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)
```

Have a look at the web page source for tag with better formatting or just clean up the on generated by my code.

Comment: Hey thanks man, give me a few minutes let me implement this and then i will accept it. I appreciate your help. I guess that does make sense, some of this website runs on Iframe's and I was wondering if that maybe was the case. Appreciate your help, talk soon